# Console style syntax highlighting

Tags: input-formats

I am using the [syntax highlighter](http://drupal.org/project/syntaxhighlighter), which is convenient. I was wondering if there is a module for a console style rendering. For example, in a [wordpress site](http://oxaric.wordpress.com/category/linux/bash-linux/), I saw

[image]

I highlighted it just to show that it is not an image of an actual terminal.

Answer (score 2):

The [GeshiFilter](http://drupal.org/project/geshifilter) module may help you.

> At the time of this writing the GeSHi library supports highlighting for more than 130 programming languages and configuration syntaxes, including: ActionScript, Ada, Apache Log, AppleScript, ASM, ASP, **Bash**, C, ColdFusion, C++, QT, C#, CSS, D, Delphi, Diff, DOS, dot, Eiffel, Fortran, Groovy, Haskell, HTML, INI, Inno, Java, Javascript, LaTeX, Lisp, Lua, Motorola 68000 Assembler, Matlab, mIRC Scripting, MySQL, Objective C, OCaml, OpenOffice.org Basic, Oracle 8 SQL, Pascal, Perl, PHP, PL/SQL, Python, QBasic/QuickBASIC, Rails, Microsoft Registry, robots.txt, Ruby, SAS, Scheme, Smalltalk, Smarty, SQL, TCL, Text, Visual Basic, vb.net, VHDL, XML, X++.